# Number of paths between two nodes in mesh topology

Tags: graphs, counting

Is there any way to find generalized formula to calculate the number of paths of different length between two nodes of the network connected in mesh topology, given that the network contains n nodes?

Comment: What were meshes again? Something like $ G =(V,E)$ with $V=\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $E = \{((a_1,...,a_n),(b_1,...,b_n)) \in V^2: \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i-b_i| = 1\}$?

Comment: @G.Bach. Imagine a Go board with processors at the intersections. Each processor connects to the others one connection above, below, left, and right. To make a long story short, you're right.

Comment: Can you repeat a node in a path?

Comment: At least initially the question mean to say you cannot repeat. However if you repeat then their are infinite paths I guess, as we can always create new path from existing path by adding one more repeating node anywhere in between. Am I correct?